# Find the probability of needing at least $3$ trials to draw a heart.

Tags: probability

> A person draws a card from a pack of $52$, replaces it and shuffles it.
>   He continues doing so until he draws a heart. What is the probability
>    that he has to make at least $3$ trials?
>
> $a.)\ \dfrac{3}{17} \\
> b.)\ \dfrac{8}{19} \\
> c.)\ \dfrac{2}{17} \\
> \color{green}{d.)\ \dfrac{11}{16}} $

First two turns will not draw a heart and last turn will draw a heart.

$\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^{2}\times \dfrac14=\dfrac{9}{64}$

But that is not in options.

I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths up to $12$th grade.

Comment: Your computation gives the probability that it takes exactly three trials, but that is not what you were asked.  You must also consider the possibility that you draw three "non-hearts" in a row.

Comment: On looking more closely, I don't see the correct answer in the list.  That's odd.  The way I see the problem:  Saying you need at least $3$ trials is the same as saying the first two fail.  The probability of the first two failing is $(\frac 34)^2=\frac 9{16}$ so that's the answer.  I see that it's not one of the options, but I don't see a flaw in my reasoning.

Comment: Can u expand ur answer in answer section.

Comment: @lulu I came to the same conclusion. Perhaps there was a mistake in the original assigned question.

Answer (score 2):

As requested in the comments:

Saying that three or more trials are required is the same as saying that the first two trials fail.  That is to say, the only reason you would ever go to the third trial is if you fail on both of the first two attempts.  Now, it makes no difference whether or not you succeed on the third trial...the problem only asks for the probability that you reach the third trial.

Now, the probability that you fail on the first two trials is $$\left(\frac 34\right)^2=\frac 9{16}$$

Therefore, this is the answer.  I note that this is not one of the available choices, but I have to assume that this is the result of some error or other in the statement of the question.